# Spring boot Couldn't find PersistentEntity

Tags: java, spring-boot, r2dbc

My Repository

```
 @Repository
 public interface TasksRepository extends LcR2dbcRepository<Task,Integer> {

   default Flux<Task> findAllTasks(){
        return   SelectQuery.from(Task.class,"root") //Ic spring data r2dbc query
                    .join("root","due","mydue")
                 .execute(getLcClient()).doOnError(System.out::println);
          }
     }
```

Task model

```
 @Getter
 @Setter
 @Builder
 @AllArgsConstructor
 @NoArgsConstructor
 @Table
 public class Task  {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column
    private Integer id;
    @Column
    private Integer comment_count;
    @Column
    private Boolean completed;
    @Column
    private String  content;
    @Column
    private String  url;
    @Column
    private Integer orderdata;
    @Column
    private Integer priority;

    @ForeignKey // this is Ic spring data r2dbc library anotation
    private Integer due;


 }
```

Due Class

```
 @Getter
 @Setter
 @NoArgsConstructor
 @AllArgsConstructor
 @Builder
 @Table
 public class Due  {

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue
   @Column
   private Integer id;
   @Column
   private Date my_data;
   @Column
   private Boolean recurring;
   @Column
   private String my_string;

 }
```

Errors

```
 org.springframework.data.mapping.MappingException: Couldn't find PersistentEntity for type class 
   java.lang.Integer!
  at 
    org.springframework.data.mapping.context.MappingContext
.getRequiredPersistentEntity(MappingContext.java:7 
 9) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
 Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException: 
 Error has been observed at the following site(s):
|_ checkpoint ⇢ Select from Task as root join mydue
|_ checkpoint ⇢ Handler 
 com.WebFluxTestCodes.WebFluxTestCodes.controller.TasksController#getAllTasks() [DispatcherHandler]
|_ checkpoint ⇢ HTTP GET "/api/tasks" [ExceptionHandlingWebHandler]
```

Hello, I am writing a project using r2dbc and I used this libary https://github.com/lecousin/lc-spring-data-r2dbc#lc-spring-data-r2dbc there, but when I use it it gives me an error saying there is no persistentity integer type. What is the problem ???

Comment: So it looks that you forget @Entity annotations on your Model classes

Comment: I wrote it again gives the same error